# MongoDB sort is slow for non-index dynamic field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Following is my MongoDB query to show the organization listing along with the user count per organization. As per my data model, the "users" collection has an array userOrgMap which maintains the organizations ( by orgId) to which the user belongs to. The "organization" collection doesn't store the list of assigned users in its collection. The "users" collection has 11,200 documents and the "organizations" has 10,500 documents.

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
{$lookup : {from:"users",localField:"_id", foreignField:"userOrgMap.orgId",as:"user" }},
{ $project : {_id:1,name:1,"noOfUsers":{$size:"$user"}}},
{$sort:{noOfUsers:-1},
{$limit : 15},
{$skip : 0}
]);
```

Without the sort, the query works fast. With the sort, the query works very slow. It takes around 200 secs.

I even tried another way which is also taking more time.

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
    {$lookup : {from:"users",localField:"_id", foreignField:"userOrgMap.orgId",as:"user" }},
    {$unwind:"$user"}
    {$group :{_id:"$_id"},name:{"$firstName":"$name"},userCount:{$sum:1}},
    {$sort:{noOfUsers:-1},
    {$limit : 15},
    {$skip : 0}
    ]);
```

For the above query, without the $sort itself takes more time.

Need help on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get the aggregation to use an index that begins with noOfUsers as I do not see a $match stage here.

Comment: There is a $match stage to filter an internal organization which has 750 users. Even with the $match the query is slow.

Comment: Do you mean that we need to create an index on noOfUsers ? Please explain

Comment: Show the entire aggregation.  Typically, an index should begin with all the fields in your match stage immediately followed by your sort fields. I will give you the command to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I created an index on "userOrgMap.orgId". The query is fast now.